# Animation doesn't work after export

Tags: modeling, animation

So I use Mixamo for my model, then I export it with .dae extension. After that, I imported it to my Blender and the animation work. However after I exported it to .obj, the animation doesn't work at all and if I export it to .babylon, the model will be abstract but the animation work. How do I solve this if I want my .obj animation to work out?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58624/how-to-export-animation-from-blender-to-3ds-or-obj-file-without-loosing-animat and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6868/how-to-create-and-export-multiple-animation-actions-in-blender

Comment: OBJ does not support animation.